# --min-instances google cloud function cloud shell command error

Tags: google-cloud-shell

I am trying to set the minimum number of instances for my google cloud function (not for cloud run) using the below command, but its not working, giving error ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) unrecognized arguments. I tried by removing \ as well as putting = after --min-instances, nothing working. At the same time -max-instances is working, having issue with --min-instances. I need to run using cloud shell command only, Don't want to directly setting it in GCP console. Any helpful answers please?

gcloud beta functions deploy  
--min-instances 2

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this - I'm having the same issue...